# Call vimgrep from terminal

Tags: terminal, vimgrep

I find myself wanting to use vimgrep without having an open vim session. Then, I usually open a blank vim session (by calling `vim` from the terminal) and then, for instance, `:vim /pattern/ *.tex`.

I was wondering whether there is a direct way to call vimgrep from the terminal and end up with an open vim session and a populated quickfix list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It concerns more shell than an editor. I guess, adding this to shell's profile should work

```
vimgrep() { $EDITOR "+vimgrep $1 $2" "+copen"; }
```

To call from terminal do not forget to put single quotation marks:

```
vimgrep '/pattern/' '*.tex'
```

Comment: $EDITOR might be anything, not even vim related. It should probably only be called with vim or nvim.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Anyone who asks a question on this site while setting `$EDITOR` to smth. else should be persecuted ;-) Seriously, any other suggestion would be even less portable.